# Proving that a real-valued function is measurable.

Tags: limits, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I was working on an exercise related to the *Monotone Convergence Theorem* applied on Lebesgue integration, and one of its hypothesis is that, for each $n$, the function $f_n(x)$ has to be measurable. Below I write the full theorem:

**Theorem.** *Let $\{f_k(x)\}$ be a nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative measurable functions with limit f. Then*
\begin{equation*}
\int f d\mu =\lim \int fd\mu.
\end{equation*}

My main problem on solving this exercises is on proving the measurability of $f_n(x)$, for each $n$. I think it might not be hard, but I am just not getting the point... Below I drop the example I was talking about in the beginning.

**Example.** *Evaluate the following limit*
\begin{equation*}
\lim_n \int_0^{n\pi} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)x^2e^{-x^3}dx.
\end{equation*}
I defined my sequence $f_n$ as $f_n(x) =\cos\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)x^2e^{-x^3}$, for $x \in [0,n\pi]$ and for each $n$. How would I prove that, for each $n$, $f_n(x)$ is a measurable function? I know the definition of a measurable function, which relates the inverse image being measurable for every open set on the domain, but I still don't get it!

**Note** I was able to prove all the other hypothesis and to solve the exercise, assuming that each $f_n$ was measurable.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: The measurability of each $f_n$ seems to be a hypothesis of the theorem.

Comment: Yes... so I need to prove it to use the theorem, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions $f_n$ in the exercise are continuous. Continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable (assuming the standard measures/topologies).

Edit: As Ilya pointed out, to apply the MCT we should rectify the issue that the functions $f_n$ are defined on different intervals $I_n$, as well as each integral. To do so, we can extend $f_n$ to $\tilde{f}_n \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\tilde{f}_n = f_n \chi_{[0,n\pi]}$$

Then by continuity, $f_n$ is measurable, and we know that $\chi_{[0,n\pi]}$ is measurable. Their product is thus measurable, and we find that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\tilde{f}_n = \int_0^{n\pi}f_n$$
allowing us to apply the theorem.

Comment: So, basically, when I am working with a function $f: \mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$, continuity $\Rightarrow$ measurability ?

Comment: His functions are defined over different intervals at the moment. Instead one should define them over the same space. One can take their product with the indicators of the correspondent intervals, which yields a function measurable on the whole real line as a product of a continuous functions and an indicator of a measurable set.

Comment: Good point thank you @Ilya. Editing the answer.

Comment: @rpd Essentially yes.